# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported type [TEXT] of value String

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a simple graph that looks like this (a couple of persons that gave reviews to movies)

```
(p: Person)-[r: review {rating}]->(m: Movie)
```

I want to create a graph accordantly the exemple from [GDS Node Similarity](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/node-similarity/) and I use this:

```
 CALL gds.graph.create(
    'myGraph',
    ['Person', 'Movie'],
    {
        review: {
            type: 'review',
            properties: {
                rating: {
                    property: 'rating',
                    defaultValue: 1.0
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

When I try this I get the next exception:

```
Failed to invoke procedure `gds.graph.create`: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported type [TEXT] of value String("4"). Please use a numeric property.
```

I can't find any useful information in the logs why I'm getting this exception. Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the "rating" property is stored as a string. What you can do is cast it first as a float and then run the exact same GDS query.

So, first casting the rating property to a float:

```
MATCH ()-[r:review]->()
SET r.rating = toFloat(r.rating)
```

Now rerun the same GDS query and it should work.